# Racemization on nucleophilic substitution by OH- ion

Tags: stereochemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

Here's the question I'm stumped by -
[image]

According to the answer key, i) is the answer but why can't it be iv)? There is a chiral carbon in compound c) CH3(C2H5)**C**HCH2Br , so why won't the product (2-Methyl-1-butanol show enantiomers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points to consider:

- In said substitution, $\ce{OH^-}$ is the nucleophile (the agent), and $\ce{Br^-}$ the nucleofuge leaving the molecule.
- While both **a)** and **c)** *contain* a stereogenic centre, only in the case of substitution **a)** this happenz *on this very* stereogenic centre.

Thus the answer key points to option i).

---

As pointed out by `@Snijderfrey`'s comment, the question equally aims to reflect on the mechanism of the reaction.  None of the formulae in the question explicitly states if the stereogenic centres in molecules **a)** or **c)** are in (*R*), or (*S*)-configuration one may convey with the wedge notation. Of course, an individual stereogenic centre is either one; describing the molecules of the sample (i.e., an ensemble) maybe this was left out because it is a mixture of (*R*) and (*S*) of these molecules (special case: [racemic mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racemic_mixture)), or omitted because the sample was not characterized accordingly.  In the later case, a wavy bond may highlight this:

[image]

Typically, the presence of a stereogenic centre eventually leads to optical activity of the material which then is either dextrorotatory or laevorotatory.  However for this question, your focus should be the correct assignment of (*R*), or (*S*) in the context of the underlying mechanism.

The effect eventually recorded in the lab depends on multiple parameters; the presence of an additional stereogenic centre does not need to be synergistic.  This then leads to [circular dichroism spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dichroism) used indeed for structure elucidation.  Among publications easier to understand about this topic in the *Journal of Chemical Education* are the ones by Urbach, Thomson, and Andrews.

References:

Andrews S. S.;  Tretton J. Physical Principles of Circular Dichroism. *J. Chem. Educ.* **2020**, *97*, 4370-4376, [doi 10.1021/acs.jchemed.0c01061](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jchemed.0c01061).

Urbach, A. R. Circular Dichroism Spectroscopy in the Undergraduate Curriculum. *J. Chem. Educ.* **2010**, *87*, 891–893, [doi 10.1021/ed1005954](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed1005954).

Thomson P. I. T. Is That a Polarimeter in Your Pocket? A Zero-Cost, Technology-Enabled Demonstration of Optical Rotation. *J. Chem. Educ.* **2018**, *95*, 837–841, [doi 10.1021/acs.jchemed.7b00767](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jchemed.7b00767).

Comment: Since c) has a stereocenter, it would have optical activity right? If it doesn't show dextrorotatory and laevorotatory forms, why?

Comment: I agree with this answer. However, the question is a little hard to answer without knowing if the starting material is a racemic mixture. I suspect the question also aims that you think about the reaction mechanism, $S_N1$ vs. $S_N2$, and its implication for stereochemistry.